# How can I use roslisp on Hydro?

Tags: ros, roslisp, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We would like to use roslisp with Hydro. I have not used it before.

It looks like some of the pieces are currently missing. The wiki documentation is not up to date since Fuerte:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp

There is a ros-hydro-roslisp Ubuntu package for Precise. But, I don't see any packages like these:

```
ros-hydro-roslisp-common
ros-hydro-roslisp-support
ros-hydro-roslisp-tutorials
```

Are those packages still needed?

The tutorial page still points to the code.ros.org SVN repository. Is that correct? I did find a [ros/roslisp](https://github.com/ros/roslisp) repo on github that appears to support catkin. Is that the current source? Where are the tutorials now?

I am happy to help with fixing things up, but need some direction to get started.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83296/how-can-i-use-roslisp-on-hydro?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-28**:
@georg-bartels can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the last release of roslisp was for Groovy. My guess is that nobody really had time to take care of releasing it for Hydro. Anyway, you should be able to use roslisp from source, given lisp messages are still generated.

The only system dependency roslisp requires is `sbcl`, so make sure that it is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

Then clone the [roslisp repo](https://github.com/roslisp) into your Catkin workspace and build it. To use it, you need to start sbcl with a custom init file:

```
sbcl --load <path to roslisp>/scripts/roslisp-sbcl-init
```

I definitely suggest to use Slime, a really powerful Emacs mode for Lisp coding (I think nowadays there is also a vim port available). If you have rosemacs installed, you shouldn't need to configure anything. Just start roslisp with `M-x slime-ros`. rosemacs was hosted on kforge, so I think the official repository is gone by now, but you could check out [my clone](https://github.com/moesenle/rosemacs-debs).

If you don't have rosemacs, make sure to set the lisp binary to load `roslisp-sbcl-init` as above, e.g. by putting the following line in your emacs config:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl --load <path to roslisp>/scripts/roslisp-sbcl-init")
```

Unfortunately I don't know how the state of the tutorials is. They haven't been touched in a while and I don't have time for too much maintenance at the moment. But I guess the code in the tutorial is still valid.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-29**:
At least the roslisp package is released for Hydro as far as I can see: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/release.yaml#L1859

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-30**:
It is, ros-hydro-roslisp installs on Precise. I was asking about the roslisp_common, roslisp_support and roslisp_tutorials packages. The tutorials refer to them. Are they still needed? Where are the sources?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-30**:
Thanks for the slime recommendation, rosemacs is great. For the record, it is installable as a rosemacs-py Debian package.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-30**:
roslisp_common and roslisp_support are dry packages in Groovy. Nobody has catkinized them and therefore they are not available in Hydro. roslisp_tutorials seems to be not even in Groovy.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2013-09-30**:
`roslisp_support` is not required anymore. It contained sbcl and the roslisp tests. In recent Ubuntu versions, SBCL is new enough to be used. `roslisp_common` containts cl_tf and and an action client and server. To use it, you need to install the dry stack from source at the moment.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-30**:
OK, where is the current source? Still on code.ros.org?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2013-09-30**:
Yes. You can check it out from https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/roslisp_common/trunk

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-01**:
@Lorenz you need to migrate these repos somewhere else asap since the Willow Garage servers can go away at any time (as announced on ros-users before).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2013-10-01**:
Actually, I was hoping that one of the guys at Bremen would do that since they rely on roslisp_common. Apparently, that didn't happen so I migrated roslisp_common to github now: https://github.com/ros/roslisp_common.git

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-10-01**:
That helps, thanks! Don't forget to update the rosdistro doc links.